# How Can I Avoid Sql Circular Reference In This Instance?

Tags: sql, database, circular-reference

I have a simple app and in this app there are 2 roles. Role 1 is a Buyer and Role 2 is a Seller. A seller can setup a post to list an item for sale.  A buyer can bid on the item in a post the seller posted.

I've been thinking of a way to prevent circular reference here but I think I am over thinking it or missing another path. What would be the best way to configure this setup?

[image]

Comment: You can just join `MarketUsers` twice with different aliases.

Comment: Thanks @trincot, so would this setup be okay?  I've heard circular references like this are not a good db design.

Comment: There is no problem at all in this design. This is quite normal. This is not what I would call a circular reference. A circular reference is when you can run in circles when following relations in the direction from many-to-one. That is not the case here. Once you arrive in `MarketUsers` there is no way out via a many-to-one relation.

Comment: Thank you, that's the confirmation I needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no circular reference to worry about here. `BuyerBids` and `SellerPosts` are fact tables (where the second has details about the first), and `MarketUsers` is a dimension table.

The many-to-one relations are toward the dimension table, as is expected.

There is no cycle where you would follow relations from the many side to the one side via many-to-one. For example if you start in `SellerPosts` you have a many-to-one to `BuyerBids` and from there to `MarketUsers`, but from there we don't have an outgoing many-to-one relation linking back to where we started.

In other words, if the graph formed by many-to-one relations (as directed edges) is a directed acyclic graph (which it is, in this case), the model is not circular.